# If I create a new Nintendo ID, can I still play my games I have downloaded to an SD card?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I Was wondering if I am able to keep games that I have downloaded to an SD card if I create a new Nintendo ID.

I  dislike my Nintendo ID very much. I had not chosen it, and it is offensive to me.

Comment: Can't you ask Nintendo if they can change your NNID?

Comment: I guess i could, but i have seen that they will not change your NNID. So I'm just seeing if i would be able to create a new one and use the games/save data on my SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, unfortunately.

If you try to use an SD card with games saved on them from a different NNID, you will not be able to access them as the new NNID will not have a license for the content on the SD card.

Posts in [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997614-nintendo-3ds/answers/380181-if-i-have-a-game-on-a-sd-card-can-i-play-that-game-on-another-3ds) confirm this.

> Downloaded software and things like DLC are tied (locked) to the system on which they were downloaded. If you try to use the SD card from your system on another 3DS, that 3DS won't be able to 'see' what's on the card.
>
> no. the license for the game is stored in your 3DS.

Thus, if you want to create a new NNID, any games linked to your old NNID would need to repurchased if you want to play them on the new NNID (also, note that there will be no way to use your old saves).